# non-manifold fix with bpy script

Tags: scripting, modifiers

I have a non-manifold '.stl' mesh which I am able to fix with Blender GUI, with a boolean modifier and intersect operation, according to this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2-11OwgRqmE
After going through those stages my mesh is perfectly manifold.

I'm trying to to the same thing with a script. I'm pretty new to Blender scripting, but after a few different tries, I wrote this script:

```
    # remove non-manifold with boolean modifier with a cube:
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=5.0)
    boolModifier = obj.modifiers.new(type="BOOLEAN", name="bool")
    boolModifier.object = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
    boolModifier.operation = "INTERSECT"
    # boolModifier.use_self = True
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="bool")

    bpy.data.objects.remove(bpy.data.objects["Cube"], do_unlink=True)
```

when I run those lines it seems like nothing is hapenning and my mesh stays non-manifold.
I tried to add the line:
boolModifier.use_self = True

as the tutorial specifically mentioned to check the "self-intersect" but I'm getting an error:
AttributeError: 'BooleanModifier' object has no attribute 'use_self', even though it appears in the documentation: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BooleanModifier.html.
I am using bpy version 2.90.0.

How do I make this fix works as a script?

Thanks!

Comment: You're not using the latest version. This feature has been added after 2.90. This is the doc page for 2.90 https://docs.blender.org/api/2.90/bpy.types.BooleanModifier.html

Comment: What version of Blender are you using?  If I add a line at the top of your script to set `obj` to a non-manifold object I created and remove the '#' from the `use_self` line, it executes just fine.  Perhaps you could add a blend file to the question that has your _complete_ script and a sample character?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!
I see now that my bpy version is 2.90 while I was looking at version 3.1.1 documentation.
I'm having troubles updating bpy version to 3.1. I'm using Windows and both conda and pip installs I found have an older versions (2.9 and 2.8):
https://anaconda.org/kitsune.one/python-blender
https://pypi.org/project/bpy/

Any suggestions? 
All I want to do is fixing the non-manifold mesh, so a different approach with an older bpy version would work as well.

Thanks again!